# Unable to run Angular2 application in Android WebView API 21

Tags: android, webview, angular, systemjs

I am trying to load an Angular2 application in an Android hybrid app which uses WebView. The SDK version is 21.

I am not able to load the app. It is not able to load boot.js module.

```
        Errormessage: "undefined is not a function↵ 
Error loading http://example.com/mobile/boot.js"stack: 

"TypeError: undefined is not a function↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:764:10↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:779:5↵    
    at linkDynamicModule (http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2921:32)↵    
    at getModule (http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2889:9)↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2925:16↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11425:22↵    
    at linkDynamicModule (http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2921:32)↵    
    at getModule (http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2889:9)↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2925:16↵    
    at http://example.com/mobile/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:13555:20"
```

It seems to be a problem with the compatibility of SystemJS with the WebView that I am using. Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the SystemJS polyfills did the trick for me.